# What is the difference between to hinder and to nix?

Tags: meaning, verbs

It seems like they both mean something like *to prevent* but I prefer to know what does it mean exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**nix** transitive verb:

```
To refuse to accept or allow (something) : to say no to (something, such as a suggestion or plan)
```

**hinder:**

```
 To make (something, such as a task or action) slow or difficult.
```

**Examples of HINDER**

- The witness refused to cooperate, hindering the investigation.
- The country's economic growth is being hindered by the sanctions.